# Is it possible to call a servlet on my domain from another domain?

Tags: java, servlets, dns

I have a VPS. My website is on that vps, and I would like to have my client's websites on there as well, which is no problem.

I want to have my servlets under my domain and have the client's websites make requests to those servlets so I can avoid duplication of data. In other words, I would prefer to have the servlets all in one location (on my domain) instead of placing copies of those servlets under each domain for a client.

The question is this - is it possible to call the servlets on my domain (or context) from another domain (context)?

If so, how is this done?

Comment: If the two "domains" have global IP addresses, then yes, of course each server can make any sort of HTTP request it likes to the other -- including requests to servlets on the other IP address.  Can't answer "how it's done" without knowing more specifically what you are trying to accomplish.  Do you just want to make a raw HTTP request to the other servlet?

Comment: Did you consider web services? It'll be so much simpler (and more reuseable!).

Comment: @Kirk - the domains are on one IP address. Is that basically what it comes down to..a simple HTTP request?

Answer (score 1):

So you have one set of Servlets hosting functionality/content for a number of domains? You can do this by routing all of your domains to the same IP/host/server and then determine the requesting domain at runtime. An example of this can be seen here:

https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/showcase/multi-domain/src/main/java/com/ocpsoft/rewrite/showcase/domain/DomainRewriteConfiguration.java

This is using a [URL/request rewriting](http://ocpsoft.com/rewrite/) tool to determine the name of a domain, and load data accordingly.

If this isn't your problem, then I guess I'm not really sure what you are asking!

Comment: That's basically the idea - one set of servlets serving functionality for multiple domains. The domains are located on one IP Address. This concept is for sites I have that are built in a similar fashion. I don't think the Domain Rewrite Config is what I'm looking for...but thank you.